# Navigation Bar, Image and outline-Image included

Tags: html, css

I have a few questions:

1. How can I make the image below not interfere with the navigation bar? I've tried various height adjustments and it doesn't move.
2. How can I make the text read as a paragraph aligned to the right and the image lower and to the left- in other words the paragraph and image parallel to each other. Would this include JavaScript?
3. I also need help with the alignment of the H1.

I have only used CSS and HTML so far- I've researched everywhere and can't find my solutions. What makes it hard is I know what I want but don't know the terms used to find the solutions. Any help is appreciated! Here is my CSS code:

```
    body{
background-color: #2F3A3B;
text-align: justify;
width: 800px;


text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;

}
    ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

li {
float: left;

}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover{
background-color: #111;
}

h1{
text-align: relative;

}

.circular--portrait {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 50%;  
}

.circular--portrait img {
  width: 100%;

}

p{
position:relative;
left: 200px;
top: 40px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>About Eddie Munoz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
</head>

<div class="circular--portrait">
<img src="images/idpic.jpg">
</div>

<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class= "column-one">
 <p>Eddie Munoz has been creating art from the age of 13. While he was 
 completing his Bachelors of Applied Science in Human Relations he was 
 freelancing on the side. Eddie has created numerous character artists. 
 ljaldjflakjfldjf;lajf;lkjd;</p>
</div>



<div class="column-two">
<h1>What others are saying</h1>
<p>"Eddie is the best young talent I have had the pleasure to work with. He 
has a great eye for detail and really finds the fun in whatever project he 
is given no matter the size. Eddie strives to learn every nuance of 3D 
gaming tech as well as distributing that knowledge once learned. Eddie is an 
amazing talent that is bound for superstar status." - Billy Ashlswede, Art 
Lead at Riot Games</p>
<p>"Eddie was a highly valued Character Artist with proficiency in many 
different modeling programs. He was a very dedicated artist who frequently 
helped others and went out of his way to produce additional assets for our 
game. Eddie has not only a very technical, but also a very artistic mindset. 
All of these qualities make Eddie a great asset to any team." -Kyle Sarvas, 
Game Artist/Game Designer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: project]

Comment: first can you also add your html.. second relative is a not a possible value of text-align it can be left,right,center,justify,inherit and initial.

Comment: Hi @Alexandra A, would you please post your html code?? (If is too long just the relevant part).

Comment: Sorry about that- HTML is now added. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure it my answer satisfies want you are looking for, let me know if is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made one change to your HTML:

1. Move `circular--portrait` just before `column-one`

And several to your CSS:

1. Remove `text-align: relative;` from `h1`
2. Remove `position: relative;` from `.circular--portrait`
3. To `.circular--portrait` set a width of 25% and make it float to left
4. To `p` that is descedent of `.column-one` make float to right and width of 65% (it has to be bellow 75% to float properly)
5. To `column-two` make float to left (also works with floating right)

```css
body{
  background-color: #2F3A3B;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 800px;
  color: white;
  font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover{
  background-color: #111;
}
.circular--portrait {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.circular--portrait img {
  width: 100%;
}

.circular--portrait {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.column-one p{
  width: 65%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.column-two {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>About Eddie Munoz</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="j.css">
</head>

<body>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="circular--portrait">
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/face/face_PNG5660.png">
 </div>

 <div class= "column-one">
   <p>Eddie Munoz has been creating art from the age of 13. While he was 
   completing his Bachelors of Applied Science in Human Relations he was 
   freelancing on the side. Eddie has created numerous character artists. 
   ljaldjflakjfldjf;lajf;lkjd;</p>
 </div>



 <div class="column-two">
  <h1>What others are saying</h1>
  <p>"Eddie is the best young talent I have had the pleasure to work with. He 
  has a great eye for detail and really finds the fun in whatever project he 
  is given no matter the size. Eddie strives to learn every nuance of 3D 
  gaming tech as well as distributing that knowledge once learned. Eddie is an 
  amazing talent that is bound for superstar status." - Billy Ashlswede, Art 
  Lead at Riot Games</p>
  <p>"Eddie was a highly valued Character Artist with proficiency in many 
  different modeling programs. He was a very dedicated artist who frequently 
  helped others and went out of his way to produce additional assets for our 
  game. Eddie has not only a very technical, but also a very artistic mindset. 
  All of these qualities make Eddie a great asset to any team." -Kyle Sarvas, 
  Game Artist/Game Designer</p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's perfect Alejandro! Thanks! Looks like I need to work on my CSS! The margins and px throw me in for a loop. Thanks again!

Comment: Great @Alexandra A, If this answer your question, please mark it as accepted (that will give us both some reputation).